# How to log messages when kill switch activated and deactivated

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit, circuit-breaker

I am using kill switch for the first time.

below is the code for kill switch in my application.

```
cfg.UseKillSwitch(options => options
    .SetActivationThreshold(10)
    .SetTripThreshold(0.15)
    .SetRestartTimeout(m: 1));
```

I want add log statements when kill switch activated and deactivated

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There are log statements, the endpoint will be started/stopped and those events are logged.

Comment: then we do not need to add log statements explicitly right?

Comment: can you give any example?